# How to keep current and previous location field in database?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I am implementing solution to office relocation. One of the main task is to show where assets/furniture should be moved. I have an entity like this (shorted version):

```
@Entity
@Table
class Asset extends BaseEntity{

private String name;

@Embedded
private Localization localization;
```

Localization contains Floor (floor_id, floor_name), x_axis, y_axis;

Here is a graphic representation of my problem (on frontend side). [image]

How I can keep current and next (destination) localization in database? I've tried some ways but they did not work. Like here:

```
@Entity
@Table
class Asset extends BaseEntity{
    
private String name;
    
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="floor.id", column=@Column(name="current_floor_id")),
})
@Embedded
private Localization localization;

@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="floor.id", column=@Column(name="destination_floor_id")),
})
@Embedded
private Localization destinationLocalization;
```

But it yells at me that floor_id is not unique and should be inserted=false and updatable=false.

Another way that I've tried was @OneToOne relation with new entity Column, or even joining in query without relations.

I've heard about Hibernate Envers, maybe that is solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you need just 2 locations, I would suggest you use the approach you already mentioned i.e. keep both old and current location infos in the entity.

If you need a history, you could create an entity e.g. `AssetLocation` with a surrogate id and refer to that in the `Asset`. Just don't delete the old `AssetLocation` objects, then you can create a one-to-many association to refer to the old positions.

You could use envers as well, but there are some limitations you have to be aware of which you can read about in the documentation.